# Check registry permission without throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, registry

I have a piece of code like this

```
try
{
    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\xxxx\\yyyyy");
    // more code
}
catch
{
}
```

I don't like the use of the empty catch block. But, it's useful because if the user don't have permissions to access the Registry, nothing should be done.

This piece of code gets called many times and, apart of a bad practice, I think it has poor performance.

I've been looking for a way to check the registry permissions before trying to access it, but the only way I've found to do it it's checking for a exception with

`RegistryPermission.Demand()`

and check for a exception. So, that gives me no advantage with the initial approach.

¿Is there a way to check for the Registry access permissions without artificially throwing or having to check for exceptions?

Edit:

Well, looks like the .NET preferred way of doing this is trying to access the resource and check for exceptions. The article Yannick pointed shows how complex it is to deal with the Windows security model, looking for the desired access manually. 
So, what I'm going to do is redesign this code a little so it only checks once for the access (catching the exception) and keeps that information, instead of constantly throwing exceptions.
This has the drawback that if the user changes the security settings "on the fly", the code will keep denying access to the Registry. However, this is preferred if there isn't a simple and clean way of checking for access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating a new key, shouldn't you just check the parent's permissions once?

Edit: I am unsure if there are managed ways, but you could try CheckAccess() in Stdprov.dll: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384911%28VS.85%29.aspx

Edit2: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w66447a.aspx ?

Edit3:

> 26) Access checks in .NET
>
> In part 2, we went through performing
>   access checks using the Win32
>   AccessCheck API. Unfortunately, there
>   doesn't seem to be an equivalent
>   managed function that can perform the
>   task. It's not recommended for you
>   perform an access check in .NET.
>   Instead, you should make use of
>   role-based security to perform an
>   access check for you (This is what
>   ReadSD does. Before ReadSD writes a
>   security descriptor, it needs to check
>   if you are allowed to alter the
>   security descriptor. It does this by
>   reading the security descriptor and
>   calling GenericPrincipal.IsInRole to
>   check for group membership). This only
>   works if your objects are designed for
>   role-based security. It does not work
>   with objects secured by security
>   descriptors.
>
> If you need to perform an access check
>   on an object with a security
>   descriptor (Registry key in our case),
>   you wouldn't use AccessCheck to do so
>   (even in Win32). The proper method is
>   to open up the registry key, and if
>   the security descriptor denies access,
>   you will get an "access denied"
>   exception.
>
> In simple access checks, you may be
>   able to perform the access check
>   yourself with the help of an
>   imperative role-based security (fig.
>   38):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/accessctrl3.aspx

Comment: No, I'm using CreateSubKey to open a subkey, not to create it. If the subkey asked already exists, the function opens it.