# Check permissions for RegistryKey edit

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check registry permission without throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431783/check-registry-permission-without-throwing-exception)

How it is more correctly to check permissions for the RegistryKey edit? 
Now I write such code:

```
RegistryKey regKey = null;
try {
    regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
}
catch (SecurityException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("SecurityException: {0}", ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
}
if (null == regKey)
    Console.WriteLine("Registry key not exists, or you have not necessary permission for edit it.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Registry key successfully opened. You have necessary permission for edit it.");
```

But exceptions very bad influenced to performance. Can I check it without try/catch?

Best Regards, Andrey

Comment: @Mr. Steak Thank you! I will read it now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the RegistryPermission class? A prior to any registry operation, you should investigate whether you actually have the permission. Something like:

```
     try
    {
        var permission = new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.Read, @"PATH\TO\YOUR\KEY");
        permission.Demand();

// your code here


    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
    {
        // Handle exc
    }
```

On success you would just continue, however, in case of missing permission, an exception would occur.

Comment: So, that gives me no advantage with the initial approach.

Answer (score 0):

> But exceptions very bad influenced to performance.

Have you profiled that?  I can't imagine any other than a very contrived situation where it would matter.

Comment: Because in Windows, .NET uses Structural Exception Handling (SEH) to throw an exception, which is quite costly.

Comment: @linquize, "quite costly" is relative.  There would need to be a tight loop for the cost to become noticeable, which seems unlikely for registry access.

Comment: @Joe For example, I must have iterating at some registry keys, but each at them has individual ACL settings, wich was modified manually by administrator. At this case some child keys I can open for read/write, but for other child keys - I can't.

Comment: @Bush, how many registry keys?  There would need to be an awful lot of inaccessible keys for the exception handling overhead to make a difference.

Comment: @Joe Yes, I know, but it is interesting for me - the potential possibility to do without try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

You should read registry setting on initialization only. Do not read registry setting in every method. Then the performance penalty of exception should not notably affect the whole program.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is interesting for me - the potential possibility to do without try/catch.